# .htaccess trims #(hash) sign from parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, frameworks

Hey everyone I'm trying to build a little MVC-framework from scratch using PHP.
I'm using simple URL-scheme for this purposes **contorller/method/params**. My htaccess file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -Multiviews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

But when I'm trying to receive url string: **explorer/add/c#** via **$_GET['url']** I'm getting **explorer/add/c** Even if I encode it like this **explorer/add/c%23** still get nothing but **explorer/add/c%24 ($-symbol)** works just fine. As You can see I'm not a good server administrator, so I hope for your help guys. Let me know if you need more info from me and thanks

Answer (score 0):

The fragment is not sent to the server by a client. I.e. `#` and anything that follows will never be part of the URL your server sees.

From [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5):

> Fragment identifiers have a special role in information retrieval
> systems as the primary form of client-side indirect referencing,
> allowing an author to specifically identify aspects of an existing
> resource that are only indirectly provided by the resource owner.  As
> such, the fragment identifier is not used in the scheme-specific
> processing of a URI; instead, the fragment identifier is separated
> from the rest of the URI prior to a dereference, and thus the
> identifying information within the fragment itself is dereferenced
> solely by the user agent, regardless of the URI scheme.

If you want to redirect a URL including the fragment part, you need to implement the redirection client-side via Javascript.